# Installing Odoo on Windows Server

Tags: installation, odoo-10

I downloaded Odoo 10 on a windows server 2016 machine, I tried to start the installer several times with no response!
So I am wondering how to start the installer ?

Comment: Are you running the installer as and ADMINISTRATOR?

Comment: Yes I tried, but that was not the problem.
It worked now by running the installer with command prompt !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I started the installer using command prompt.